# How do I map a column to uppercase in .NET 4.5 C# Entity Framework 6 using both Oracle and SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, oracle, entity-framework, c#-4.0, entity-framework-6

I'm using C#, .NET 4.5 and [Entity Framework](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ADO.NET_Entity_Framework) 6 in my project. It uses both Oracle and SQL Server, depending on the installation at the client.

The approach is database-first, as this database existed already by the time we decided to change the ORM from [NHibernate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NHibernate) to Entity Framework 6.

The mapping looks like this:

```
ToTable(schema + ".Motorista");
Property(x => x.Criacao).HasColumnName("criacao").IsOptional();
```

The table and column names are all in PascalCase in the mapping, which works fine with SQL Server but, in Oracle, all the names are UpperCase which causes an error:

> ORA-00942: table or view does not exist

If I manually make it uppercase, then it works fine on Oracle. But I can't do that because of compatibility to SQL Server.

How can I say to Entity Framework to uppercase all the names when using Oracle?

Can I use conventions in this scenario?

Comment: You went from NHibernate to EF?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17185921/ef-vs-nhibernate-merge-disconnected-object-graph

Comment: A workaround would be to use a configuration value and check it conditionally in your fluent mappings and convert names to upper case if it is set.  So your client would modify this config value to specify Oracle, and your code would check that setting.  You could have a fluent style helper method `.ToAppropriateName` or similar that makes it easier to reuse.  Granted, having clients modify a config file might be painful depending on how many clients you have.  IDK if there is an easier way to programmatically check at runtime if the connection string is pointing to Oracle.

Comment: Check the providerName attribute in the named connection string to see if your connection is for Sql Server or Oracle (OR add a redundant value in the appSettings section of the config). Then do what @AaronLS suggested and add a helper method to case your names correctly and apply any additional formatting. The helper method should be tasked with checking the db type as mentioned above and applying or not applying casing/formatting.

Comment: Are table and column names always the same as class and property names (apart from case)? If so, you could use custom code first conventions.

Comment: @GertArnold yes they are all the same apart from case. How can I use the custom convention to achieve this (I'm using database first approach)? I research and found only examples for ef 4 and 5 ( I'm using 6 and some classes names were changed).
Can anyone help with some example?
THanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the providerName attribute in the named connection string to see if your connection is for SQL Server or Oracle (OR add a redundant value in the appSettings section of the configuration). Then do what @AaronLS suggested and add a helper method to case your names correctly and apply any additional formatting. The helper method should be tasked with checking the database type as mentioned above and applying or not applying casing/formatting.

Here is an example.

```
public class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new SomeMappedTypeMapper());
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
}

public class SomeMappedType
{
    public int SomeMappedColumnId { get; set; }
    public string SomeMappedColumn { get; set; }
}

public class SomeMappedTypeMapper : EntityTypeConfiguration<SomeMappedType>
{
    public SomeMappedTypeMapper()
    {
        this.HasKey(x => x.SomeMappedColumnId);
        this.ToTable("SomeMappedType"); // If needed, apply the same technique as used in the column name extension

        this.Property(x => x.SomeMappedColumnId).HasColumnNameV2("SomeMappedColumnId").HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
        this.Property(x => x.SomeMappedColumn).HasColumnNameV2("SomeMappedColumn");
    }
}

public static class TypeHelper
{
    private static bool isOracle;
    static TypeHelper()
    {
        isOracle = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["yourDbConnectionName"].ProviderName.IndexOf("oracle", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0;
    }
    public static PrimitivePropertyConfiguration HasColumnNameV2(this PrimitivePropertyConfiguration property, string columnName)
    {
        if (isOracle)
            return property.HasColumnName(columnName.ToUpper());
        return property.HasColumnName(columnName);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Igor, that Helper extension solved the problem.

Answer (score 4):

When the database names (tables and columns) are equal to the class and property names in the class model it's very easy to introduce **custom code-first conventions**:

In the context's `OnModelCreating` overload you can add these lines to add conventions how table and column names will be derived from the class and property names, respectively:

```
modelBuilder.Types().Configure
    (c => c.ToTable(c.ClrType.Name.ToUpper(), schema));

modelBuilder.Properties().Configure
    (c => c.HasColumnName(c.ClrPropertyInfo.Name.ToUpper()));
```

Of course you should do this conditionally, i.e. when connecting to Oracle. For instance by checking a global constant like `OnOracle` that you could set by

```
ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[0].ProviderName
    == "System.Data.OracleClient"
```

on application start up.

Comment: I tried this, but it just ain't triggered. I checked the generated SQL and remained the same.

Comment: Did you do this *in stead of*  the current ToTable statements?

Comment: No.. I kept the mappings and add this. Will try removing the "ToTable" mapping and keep just this Configuration.

Comment: Individual `ToTable` mappings overrule the conventions, so that's why.

Comment: this should be the accepted answer, simple and powerful. Works great, thanks! - didn't use the second block of code since all entities come from oracle

Comment: @GertArnold thanks. your post seems to be the solution to my recent problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35423692/ef-6-with-odp-net-oracle-manageddataaccess-how-to-use-non-capital-letter-for-cl

Comment: I just did it and created two tables that have many-to-many and the `-Script` option shows me columns in upper case but foreign keys are still in lower `.ForeignKey("USER.TEST2", t => t.Test2_Id, cascadeDelete: true)` and   `CreateTable("USER.Test2Test1",...` is also in lowercase

Comment: @Toolkit As I said to your other comment: raising new issues in comments is useless. We don't know all the details.

Comment: because your solution is only partially correct, at least for Oracle. You need this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35457202/631527

Answer (score 1):

This [link](https://gist.github.com/kennykanp/550a21cc4af68072cdfe4ef7b62e337b) is in EF CORE but it may help you, this converts ToUpper, but you can change ToLower, you can also use the Nuget ** Humanizer ** for another type of capitalize.

Import that file into your project and use it like this.

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    modelBuilder.ToUpperCaseTables();
    modelBuilder.ToUpperCaseColumns();
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider a table called "Person" with a column called "Name" in SQL Server but in oracle the table is called "PERSON" with a column called "NAME".

We were able to use our models generated against sql server on our oracle database by adding the following code to the DBContext classe's OnModelCreating

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Person>()
  .HasEntitySetName("Person")
  .ToTable("PERSON");

modelBuilder.Entity<Person>()
  .Property(t => t.Name)
  .HasColumnName("NAME");
```